# Django REST Framework updated nested object not in Model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I only want to update all order in my_stage by using PUT, something like:

"Payload":

```
{
"stages": [
    {
        "stage_id": 1,
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "stage_id": 2,
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "stage_id": 3,
        "position": 4
    }
]
}
```

and "Response":

```
{
"stages": [
    {
        "stage_id": 1,
        "position": 2
    },
    {
        "stage_id": 2,
        "position": 3
    },
    {
        "stage_id": 3,
        "position": 4
    }
]
}
```

But I don't have "stages" in my model so I cannot use ModelSerializer. But I have to implement create() first.
So what should I do to implement update? Thank you.

My stage model is:

```
class Stage(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'stage'
    position = models.IntegerField()
```

Here are my serialzier.py

```
class StagePositionSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """Serialize order"""
     # company_id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    stage_id = IntegerField(source='id', read_only=True)
    position = IntegerField(min_value=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Stage
        fields = [
            'stage_id',
            'position'
        ]

class PositionSerializer(Serializer):
    stages = StagePositionSerializer(many=True)
```

and my view.py

```
class StagePositionListView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PositionSerializer
```

Comment: are you asking to only have `"stages:"` prepended to the json response?

Comment: Yes, I only want to have "stages", but there is no "stages" in my model so it cannot match the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to have `"stages:"` prepended to your data you can create a custom endpoint in the viewset and specify the formatting you want returned.

I'm not sure why you have a model serializer as well as a non-model serializer. What does that buy you?

Here is some sample code which would add 'get_stages' to your api url.

`views.py:`

```
class StagePositionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StagePositionSerializer


    @list_route(methods=['GET'])
    def get_stages(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            stage_list = Stage.objects.all()
            serializer = StagePositionSerializer(stage_list , many=True)
            results = dict()
            #this is where you add your prepended info
            results['stages'] = serializer.data
            return Response(results, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
        return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Then if  you perform a GET at the URL `whatever_your_url/is/get_stages` you will get back the payload format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily take advantage of `serializer(many=True)`, which will match a list of serializers. Your serializer would be:

```
class StagePositionSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stage
        fields = [
            'id',
            'position'
        ]

class PositionSerializer(Serializer):
    stages = StagePositionSerializer(many=True)
```